# Historical Google Static Map Images

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-maps-static-api

It is possible to download recent earth images from http://staticmapmaker.com/google/.

**Question: Is there some way to download historical earth images?**

I guess google must have these somewhere, since previously it was possible to download images from 2015 from the very same webpage mentioned above.

I am aware historical images are available in Google Earth, but I have no clue how to download these in a similar way (same zoom level and size) as is possible from Google Static Maps API.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Currently there is no way to get historical imagery via Google Static Maps API.

You can see the corresponding feature request in the issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35826354

Feel free to star the feature request to add your vote and subscribe to further notifications from Google.